# Sitecore experience editor not opening in editing mode (Intermittent)

Tags: jss, experience-editor

We are having a **Sitecore 10.3 XM NextJS** docker instance. Sometimes Our Experience editor not loading properly in editing mode(**loading like a regular page**). This is intermittent though.

This is an issue with fields other than "**Single line text**" and "**Rich text**" fields. Please check below 2 screenshots. Sometimes when we reload the page this issue occurs.

[image][image]

The difference I found between 2 rendered HTMLs is, an additional input element is getting added in the non working one. PFB screenshot,
[image]

I am also getting these hydration errors in console,
[image]

Comment: Have you checked any errors logged in the console?

Comment: @SumitHelaiya - I am getting the react hydration errors in console. updated the screenshot above.

Comment: See if this works - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73162551/how-to-solve-react-hydration-error-in-nextjs

Comment: Okay, I will check this. But as per my understanding this console error is harmless. It is always there in both working and non working conditions.

Comment: quick update on this - I noticed that a sitecore cache clear resolves this issue but It is not a full proof solution.

Answer (score 0):

We are facing the same issue, but for us behavior is, it works fine on our DEV server and does not work on local somehow

My observation and debugging shows that, if you have used <Link  of JSS and if you are using `{editable:true}` that is causing the issue for us

if I make it `{editable:false}` my experience editor loads and I am able to edit other parts

Currently with `{editable:true}` I am not even able to see Add Here button but with `{editable:false}` I am able to.